# Python: Pandas: two columns with same values, alphabetically sorted and stored

Tags: python, pandas

**Problem**
"The df has two columns but sometimes filled with the same values. We need to re-save them into two new columns but in alphabetical order"

**Context**
We have a pandas df like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{"name_A": "john", "name_B": "mac"}, {"name_A": "mac", "name_B": "john"}])
```

Like this:

```
name_A | name_B
john   |  mac 
mac    |  john 
Trump  |  Clinton
```

**Desired Output**

```
name_A | name_B   | restated_A  | restated_B
john   |  mac     |  john       |  mac
mac    |  john    |  john       |  mac
trump  |  clinton |  clinton    | trump
```

In words, we wish to have the columns' values `name_A`  and `name_B` to be alphabetically sorted in `restated_A`  AND `restated_B`

**Tried so far**
bunch of lambdas but couldn't get it to work

**Specifications**
Python: 3.5.2
Pandas: 0.18.1

Comment: Please consider [accepting one of the answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative vectorized solution, you can use `numpy.minimum()` and `numpy.maximum()`:

```
import numpy as np
df['restart_A'] = np.minimum(df['name_A'], df['name_B'])
df['restart_B'] = np.maximum(df['name_A'], df['name_B'])
```

[image]

Or use `apply` method:

```
df[['restated_A', 'restated_B']] = df.apply(lambda r: sorted(r), axis = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just send `df.values` to a list and sort that list for each row. Then reassign the elements in the pairs accordingly.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{"name_A": "john", "name_B": "mac"}, {"name_A": "mac", "name_B": "john"}])
>>> restated_values = [sorted(pair) for pair in df.values.tolist()]
>>> restated_values
[['john', 'mac'], ['john', 'mac']]
>>> df['restated_A'] = [pair[0] for pair in restated_values]
>>> df
  name_A name_B restated_A
0   john    mac       john
1    mac   john       john
>>> df['restated_b'] = [pair[1] for pair in restated_values]
>>> df
  name_A name_B restated_A restated_b
0   john    mac       john        mac
1    mac   john       john        mac
```

Or, you could do this, using a `dict` and a new `pandas.DataFrame` object:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{"name_A": "john", "name_B": "mac"}, {"name_A": "mac", "name_B": "john"}])
>>> restated_values = [sorted(pair) for pair in df.values.tolist()]
>>> restated_values
[['john', 'mac'], ['john', 'mac']]
>>> new_col_rows = {'restated_A': [pair[0] for pair in restated_values], 'restated_B': [pair[1] for pair in restated_values]}
>>> new_col_rows
{'restated_A': ['john', 'john'], 'restated_B': ['mac', 'mac']}
>>> new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_col_rows)
>>> new_df
  restated_A restated_B
0       john        mac
1       john        mac
>>> df = df.join(new_df)
>>> df
  name_A name_B restated_A restated_B
0   john    mac       john        mac
1    mac   john       john        mac
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use NumPy [sort()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sort.html) method in order to sort "in place":

```
In [57]: df
Out[57]:
  name_A   name_B
0   john      mac
1    mac     john
2  Trump  Clinton

In [58]: df.values.sort(axis=1)

In [59]: df
Out[59]:
    name_A name_B
0     john    mac
1     john    mac
2  Clinton  Trump
```

**Timing against 30K rows DF:**

```
In [69]: %%timeit
    ...: big = pd.concat([df.copy()] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)
    ...: big.values.sort(axis=1)
    ...:
1 loop, best of 3: 2.25 s per loop

In [70]: %%timeit
    ...: big = pd.concat([df.copy()] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)
    ...: big.apply(lambda r: sorted(r), axis = 1)
    ...:
1 loop, best of 3: 15.9 s per loop

In [71]: %%timeit
    ...: big = pd.concat([df.copy()] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)
    ...: pd.DataFrame([sorted(pair) for pair in big.values.tolist()], columns=df.columns)
    ...:
1 loop, best of 3: 2.29 s per loop
```

**Timing against 300K rows DF:**

```
In [73]: %%timeit
    ...: big = pd.concat([df.copy()] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)
    ...: big.values.sort(axis=1)
    ...:
1 loop, best of 3: 23 s per loop

In [74]: %%timeit
    ...: big = pd.concat([df.copy()] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)
    ...: big.apply(lambda r: sorted(r), axis = 1)
    ...:
1 loop, best of 3: 2min 39s per loop

In [75]: %%timeit
    ...: big = pd.concat([df.copy()] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)
    ...: pd.DataFrame([sorted(pair) for pair in big.values.tolist()], columns=df.columns)
    ...:
1 loop, best of 3: 23.4 s per loop
```